# pagination in entity framework and refactoring

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an api end point which returns the paginated result, the corresponding code for that is as below:

```
public Task<PaginatedDataResult<ProductSearchResult>> GetPaginatedSearchAsync(int currentPage,
                                                                                      int perPage,
                                                                                      string nameFilter,
                                                                                      string sortBy,
                                                                                      bool sortDesc,
                                                                                      CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            IEnumerable<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>> GetFilters()
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameFilter))
                {
                    var normalizedNameFilter = nameFilter.NormalizeUpper();
                    yield return p => p.NormalizedName.Contains(normalizedNameFilter);
                }
            }

        Expression<Func<Product, ProductSearchResult>> projectionExpression =
            p => new ProductSearchResult
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                Name = p.Name,
                EndDate = p.EndDate,
                IsActive = p.IsActive,
                ServicesCount = p.ProductServices.Count
            };

        return PaginatedFilterWithProjectionAsync(currentPage, perPage, sortBy, sortDesc, cancellationToken, projectionExpression, GetFilters().ToArray());
    }
    
    
    protected async Task<PaginatedDataResult<TProjectedEntity>>
        PaginatedFilterWithProjectionAsync<TProjectedEntity>(int currentPage,
            int perPage,
            string sortBy,
            bool sortDesc,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken,
            Expression<Func<TEntity, TProjectedEntity>> projectionExpression,
            params Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>[] filters
        ) where TProjectedEntity : class
    {
        var query = filters.Aggregate(DbSet.AsQueryable(), (q, f) => q.Where(f));
        var queryWithProjection = query.Select(projectionExpression);


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy))
        {
            queryWithProjection = sortDesc
                ? queryWithProjection.OrderByDescending(sortBy)
                : queryWithProjection.OrderBy(sortBy);
        }

        var filteredQueryOfProjectedEntity = queryWithProjection
            .Skip((currentPage - 1) * perPage)
            .Take(perPage);

        var filteredListOfProjectedEntity = await filteredQueryOfProjectedEntity.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        var count = await queryWithProjection.CountAsync(cancellationToken);

        return new PaginatedDataResult<TProjectedEntity>
        {
            PerPage = perPage,
            CurrentPage = currentPage,
            TotalCount = count,
            Data = filteredListOfProjectedEntity
        };
    }
```

Now, I have another end point which is returning a complete collection as below

```
    public async Task<ICollection<ProductRelationship>> GetAllByRelationshipDataAsync(
        bool includeDetail,
        bool filterActiveProduct = false,
        DateTime? filterActiveRelationshipDate = null,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {            

        var set = includeDetail ? IncludeDetail(DbSet) : DbSet;
       
        //I have removed few parameters from the method and also few if conditions for brevity
        if (filterActiveProduct)
        {
            set = set.Where(x => x.Product != null && x.Product.IsActive);
        }

        if (filterActiveRelationshipDate.HasValue)
        {
            var filterDate = filterActiveRelationshipDate.Value.Date;
            set = set.Where(x => x.StartDate <= filterDate && (!x.EndDate.HasValue || x.EndDate.Value >= filterDate));
        }

        return await set.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

The requirement is to change the above method to return a paginated result, so the changes I did are as below:

1. change the method signature to add four additional parameters (currentPage, perPage, sortBy, sortDesc)
2. Rather than returning a collection, calling a PaginatedAsync method to return paginated result

   ```
            public async Task<PaginatedDataResult<ProductRelationship>> GetAllByRelationshipDataAsyncTest(
    bool includeDetail,       
    int currentPage,
    int perPage,
    string sortBy,
    bool sortDesc,
    bool filterActiveProduct = false,
    DateTime? filterActiveRelationshipDate = null,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {                

            var set = includeDetail ? IncludeDetail(DbSet) : DbSet;

            //I have removed few parameters from the method and also few if conditions for brevity

            if (filterActiveProduct)
            {
                set = set.Where(x => x.Product != null && x.Product.IsActive);
            }

            if (filterActiveRelationshipDate.HasValue)
            {
                var filterDate = filterActiveRelationshipDate.Value.Date;
                set = set.Where(x => x.StartDate <= filterDate && (!x.EndDate.HasValue || x.EndDate.Value >= filterDate));
            }

            return await PaginatedAsync(set, currentPage, perPage, sortBy, sortDesc, cancellationToken);
        }
   ```

   3. PaginatedAsync method is the same copy of PaginatedFilterWithProjectionAsync method above but without the variables query and queryWithProjection, since I have got the queryWithProjection value in the variable set above.
      I could also refactor the PaginatedFilterWithProjectionAsync method to include PaginatedAsync as most of the code is same, but that was already in use, that adds more testing effort. May be I am breaking open closed principle

      ```
      protected async Task<PaginatedDataResult<TProjectedEntity>> PaginatedAsync<TProjectedEntity>(IQueryable<TProjectedEntity> queryWithProjection, int currentPage,
          int perPage,
          string sortBy,
          bool sortDesc,
          CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      {
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy))
          {
              queryWithProjection = sortDesc
                  ? queryWithProjection.OrderByDescending(sortBy)
                  : queryWithProjection.OrderBy(sortBy);
          }

          var filteredQueryOfProjectedEntity = queryWithProjection
              .Skip((currentPage - 1) * perPage)
              .Take(perPage);

          var filteredListOfProjectedEntity = await filteredQueryOfProjectedEntity.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

          var count = await queryWithProjection.CountAsync(cancellationToken);

          return new PaginatedDataResult<TProjectedEntity>
          {
              PerPage = perPage,
              CurrentPage = currentPage,
              TotalCount = count,
              Data = filteredListOfProjectedEntity
          };
      }
      ```

Please can anyone review and provide me with suggestions for better approach and point me the mistakes in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Some quick remarks:

- There are almost 90 white-space characters before I can see the arguments to `GetPaginatedSearchAsync`. In such cases, move the parameters to the next line.
- Consider renaming `PaginatedDataResult` and `ProductSearchResult` (is the "Result" part of the name necessary?), and even `GetPaginatedSearchAsync` (is there a non-async method? if not, then why add this to the method name?).
- `GetPaginatedSearchAsync` has six parameters: that is bordering on the limit, and I'd advise you to pass a custom class instead. You could at least group the pagination-related parameters into their own class.
- Do not pointlessly abbreviate names. I get what `sortDesc` means but it still is jarring to read.
- Judging by `//I have removed few parameters from the method and also few if conditions for brevity` it seems you realized the amount of parameters grew too large and impacted readability. Consider moving all of the filter-related parameters into a class of their own and pass that class instead of an ever-growing and thus hard to maintain list.
- IMHO you should avoid pointlessly detailed variable names like `filteredQueryOfProjectedEntity` and `filteredListOfProjectedEntity`, and even `queryWithProjection` (why assign `query` only to immediately apply `Select` to it on the next line and then never use it again? why not combine these two lines and simply use `query` instead of `queryWithProjection`?). These make your code hard to read. Instead, I'd expect these names to convey more of a concept.

Answer (score 1):

One main remark: the paging method is too busy. The number of arguments is a tell-tale. The parts that don't belong there are filtering and sorting.

In general, a method returning any paged result, should only receive an `IQueryable` and the paging instructions page number and page size. Your second method is almost there. After removing the superfluous responsibilities, what's left is:

```cs
protected async Task<PaginatedDataResult<TEntity>> PaginateAsync<TEntity>(
    IQueryable<TEntity> query, int pageNumber, int pageSize,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var pageQuery = query
        .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize);

    var page = await pageQuery.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

    var count = await query.CountAsync(cancellationToken);

    return new PaginatedDataResult<TEntity>
    {
        PerPage = pageSize,
        CurrentPage = pageNumber,
        TotalCount = count,
        Data = page
    };
}
```

Now you have a method that you can offer any `IQueryable`. It doesn't need to know if it's a `DbSet` or a projection, or filtered, or ordered. The count of the query is independent of all these details. [In fact, when using Entity Framework, you won't even see the projection in the generated SQL count query)].

This makes each method that calls `PaginateAsync` responsible for composing the `IQueryable` they want to have paged. And —the main point— now it's possible to have a method that just returns the `IQueryable` and another method that takes this `IQueryable` and returns a page.

So, you'll just keep `GetAllByRelationshipDataAsync`, which I would at least shorten to `GetAllByRelationshipAsync`, and add a method `GetAllByRelationshipPagedAsync` that looks like your `GetAllByRelationshipDataAsyncTest` method, but now internally just executes
`GetAllByRelationshipAsync` and `PaginateAsync`.

Likewise, `GetPaginatedSearchAsync` should be changed to contain the filtering and ordering parts, so it will be able to call `PaginateAsync` as well.

Of course, if you want, you can create separate methods that execute filtering and/or ordering.

Now it's even possible to have a service layer that's just bothered with composing queries and doesn't even contain any paging logic. The paging method could be part of the controller layer only.